# Loop through multiple json files using plain js

Tags: javascript, json

I want to loop through multiple .json files using plain js and get certain values like "datum" and "content" etc. (all .json files look the same).

As of now, only one .json file is loaded: `var json_file = loadString('data.json');`

The name of the .json files is 170.json, 171.json, ... 2741.json.

```
function draw() {

  var json_file = loadString('data.json');
  var obj = JSON.parse(json_file);
  var arrayLength = obj.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    text(obj[i].datum, 44.5, 20, 93, 10);
    text(obj[i].content, 44.5, 30.44, 93, 10);
  }
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: you can iterate over the file names and load them in a loop can't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the files using another `for` loop

```
function draw() {
    for (a = 0; a > number.of.files.length; a++) {
          var json_file = loadString('${a}.json');
          var obj = JSON.parse(json_file);
          var arrayLength = obj.length;

          for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

              text(obj[i].datum, 44.5, 20, 93, 10);
              text(obj[i].content, 44.5, 30.44, 93, 10);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Odd. Regarding `var json_file = loadString("~/Desktop/seminar_robobooks/archiv/json/"a + '.json');` it gives me an error "Syntax error: Expected: )". Seems like it's the "a".

Comment: Try with a template string instead. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 // we need a function to load files
    // done is a "callback" function
    // so you call it once you're finished and pass whatever you want
    // in this case, we're passing the `responseText` of the XML request
       var loadFile = function (filePath, done) {
        var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () { return done(this.responseText) }
        xhr.open("GET", filePath, true);
        xhr.send();
    }
    // paths to all of your files
    var myFiles = [ "file1", "file2", "file3" ];
    // where you want to store the data
    var jsonData = [];
    // loop through each file
    myFiles.forEach(function (file, i) {
        // and call loadFile
        // note how a function is passed as the second parameter
        // that's the callback function
        loadFile(file, function (responseText) {
            // we set jsonData[i] to the parse data since the requests
            // will not necessarily come in order
            // so we can't use JSONdata.push(JSON.parse(responseText));
            // if the order doesn't matter, you can use push
            jsonData[i] = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var arrayLength = jsonData.length;
            // or you could choose not to store it in an array.
            // whatever you decide to do with it, it is available as
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

        text(obj[i].datum, 44.5, 20, 93, 10);
        text(obj[i].content, 44.5, 30.44, 93, 10);
      }
            // responseText within this scope (unparsed!)
        }
    })
```